# Can Query Store readonly reason 262144 be removed without clearing the Query Store?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory, query-store

I recently had Query Store enter readonly mode due to Readonly Reason 262144. It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-query-store-options-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

> 262144 - Size of in-memory items waiting to be persisted on disk has reached the internal memory limit. Query Store will be in read-only mode temporarily until the in-memory items are persisted on disk.

and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2019/cumulativeupdate8#136632000).

> Query Store scalability improvement for adhoc workloads. Query Store now imposes internal limits to the amount of memory it can use and automatically changes the operation mode to READ-ONLY until enough memory has been returned to the Database Engine, preventing performance issues.

The only way that I could get Query Store to leave this state was to `ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;`. As suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16#Verify). **Is there any other solution?** When SQL Server mentions memory, it typically means RAM, but the solution being to clear all Query Store info seems to contradict that idea. **What actually causes this?**

I know that changing `QUERY_CAPTURE_MODE` to `AUTO` and running

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF
Exec [MyDB].dbo.sp_query_store_consistency_check
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET QUERY_STORE = ON
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE)
```

can fix reason 131072

> 131072 - The number of different statements in Query Store has reached the internal memory limit. Consider removing queries that you do not need or upgrading to a higher service tier to enable transferring Query Store to read-write mode.

but I do not yet know if that applies here.

Comment: Does this not work for you? `ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE)`

Comment: @SeanGallardy In my experience, that never works when you have hit an error that automatically changes the operation mode to READ-ONLY.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @SeanGallardy I'm confident that I did.